# 1000000 consecutive numbers divisible by the square of a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am trying to prove there exist 1000000 consecutive numbers divisible by the square of a prime.

I have already tried several ways

- prove that the alternative is impossible didn’t work because it’s easy to find a million numbers that are not all non-prime;
- I tried ‘constructing’ a list, by starting from a random list and multiplyingcto get squares of primes, no luck…

I am currently traveling with limited network, so it’s difficult to look up tips online.  If anyone can give me a hint in the right direction, that would be much appreciated…

Thanks!

Comment: I would assume that using the Chinese Remainder Theorem would be really useful here

Comment: Thanks! This was actually so obvious…

Comment: I was chatting with a colleague in another field a few years ago.  I said something about CRT and he said, "Well, what else do number theorists have?"  I said, "Um.....uh.....OH!.... no wait....um....."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pick three primes $p, q,$ and $r$. Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve the system

$$n \equiv 0 \pmod{p^2}$$
$$n \equiv -1 \pmod{q^2}$$
$$n \equiv -2 \pmod{r^2}$$

Then $p^2\mid n$,  $q^2\mid n+1$, $r^2\mid n+2$.

So there are three consecutive numbers divisible by the square of a prime.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 1):

First, let's tackle smaller versions of the problem.

Let $f(n)$ be the smallest positive integer $k$ such that all $n$ integers between $k$ and $k + n - 1$ are divisible by the square of a prime.  By simple brute force:

- $f(1) = 4$
- $f(2) = 8$
- $f(3) = 48$
- $f(4) = 242$
- $f(5) = 844$

And this is enough values to search OEIS and find that someone has already implemented this sequence and published it as [A045882](https://oeis.org/A045882).  So you “just” need an efficient algorithm to find $f(1000000)$, which according to the linked page *does* exist because the sequence is infinite.

Comment: This was what I was trying to force-construct. I will look into this as wel well, as I like that direction

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).